# How can I read a text file into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was wondering how I can go about reading a text file into an array, the text file would contain something along the lines of:

```
string:string:string
string:string:string
string:string:string
etc
```

(string:string:string being on a single line)

Comment: so basically a CSV using colons instead of commas?

Comment: read each line of file, split it by `:` and put each token to array/List

Comment: the delimeters would not need to be split at this time, I would just be reading each line as a whole into an array cell, also ive looked around on google but was not able to find anything of use unfortunately :/

Comment: @lacrosse1991 I am making a wild guess as to what you are looking for so have updated my answer accordingly..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I think you might want to read a file into an array but you don't know set the size of an array. You can use a `java.util.ArrayList` for that and then convert it to an array.

```
FileReader fin = new FileReader(fileName);
Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
src.useDelimiter(":");

while (src.hasNext()) {
    lines.add(src.nextLine());
    // replace above line with array
}
String[] lineArray = new String[lines.size()];
lines.toArray(lineArray);
```

You can use the `java.util.Scanner` class and then use the `useDelimiter` function.

```
FileReader fin = new FileReader(fileName);
Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);

src.useDelimiter(":");

while (src.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(src.next());
    // replace above line with array
}
```

Example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/SettingDelimitersforScanner.htm)